# To multi insert in cql for scala

Tags: scala, cql

I want to insert the result of first query in second query, I need to know how to multi insert values in Cassandra Query Language.Please enlighten me.

```
def daomethod(seconditemtable:SecondItemTable):java.util.List[Row]={

    val query=session.execute("select item from itemtable").all()     //first query

    val queryvalue=query.map(x=>x.getString("item")).toList.distinct   //List(item1,item2,item3)


    val secondquery="select * from seconditemtable where entity=? and item=? and date>=? and date<=?"  //second  query

    val statement=session.prepare(secondquery)

    val boundstatement= new Boundstatement(statement)

    session.execute(boundstatement.bind(seconditemtable.entity,queryvalue,seconditemtable.date,seconditemtable.date)).all()     //how to insert multiple value of firstquery in item column
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that

```
val secondquery=s"select * from seconditemtable where entity=? and item in (${queryvalue.mkString(",")}) and date>=? and date<=?"
```

to take advantage of cql in statement.
More details on it https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html

Comment: hi ,it is not accepting List values,it needs to be passed single value,and mkstring puts ',' between all the chars ...thanks anyways

Comment: `select * from seconditemtable where item in (item1, item2)` is a valid cql request, but you have to put quotes around 'item1' if it's a string. Sorry if it's not useful.